# Java variable inside "if" not recognized

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I have assignment to create an atm program for my class. I've mostly done everything except this one problem. The variable inside an if statement is not recognized. I want to create somekind of id check, the code for assigning the variable to true is not recognized, the else statement that assign the false value is working fine. Here is the code:

```
boolean k;
String trf = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert [ID <space> Amount]:");
StringTokenizer tr = new StringTokenizer(trf);
tid = tr.nextToken();
int tam = Integer.parseInt(tr.nextToken());
for(int x=0;x<4;x++){
    if (t[x].account.getId().equals(tid)){
       k = true;
       //transfer code here[...]
       break;
    }
    else{
       k=false;
    }
    if(!k){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID not found");
    }
}
```

I read some other topic like this before an one said to define the variable before the if, but i cant do that in my case because i need to check the value first. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you might need to include the "transfer code" part in order for your question to make sense.  I don't know what your exact problem is.

Comment: its not only used in transfer but in login too so this is the general code

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Cause for me, it runs pretty fine: http://ideone.com/SD8Y4K

Comment: @Abhineet the problem is the statement that define variable k as true not recognized, so it always result in false. The accepted answer already solved it.

Comment: What do you mean by not recognized?

Comment: The true value is not recognized outside if, its value became false. But if you used it inside if the value is true, well something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do this:

```
boolean k = false;
String trf = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert [ID <space> Amount]:");
StringTokenizer tr = new StringTokenizer(trf);
tid = tr.nextToken();
int tam = Integer.parseInt(tr.nextToken());
for(int x=0;x<4;x++){
    if (t[x].account.getId().equals(tid)){
       k = true;
       //transfer code here[...]
       break;
    }
}
if(!k){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID not found");
}
```

Comment: It says "the variable k might have not been initialized" if i put the last if outside of loop

Comment: Look my code. I have already initialized. boolean k = false; have you checked that line?

Comment: Your variable seems like local variable so it will not be initialized to default value. Otherwise it will be automatically initialized to false.

Comment: If for example i declare the variable in the main class i don't need to initialized it to false, right?

Comment: Your solution is just but it don't answer why the OP's code snippet is not working. I am just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Transfer the last `if statement` out of the `for` loop

```
for(int x=0;x<4;x++){
    if (t[x].account.getId().equals(tid)){
       k = true;
       //transfer code here[...]
       break;
    }
    else{
       k=false;
    }

}
if(!k){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID not found");
    }
```

The way it was written the last statement would not be executed if the first `if` was evaluated to `true` due to `break`

Comment: It says "the variable k might have not been initialized"

Comment: @Dizz Initialize `k` to `false` to get rid of the warning. Then you can also remove the `else` part of the `if`.

Comment: If you do that the logic of OP's program is broken... And regarding the said problem, it's even worse (as `k` initialization is even less obvious for the Java compiler in this case).

Comment: @ringø Sorry care to elabrate? My program work ok now actually. But if you have some advice to improve my program i'll gladly accept.

Comment: @Dizz Well, maybe the outcome of your new program does something satisfactory that is not reflected by the logic of the algorithm in the question (which is related to `k` possibly not initialized - not its logic). Reading the question, `k` is always assigned before being tested, but the compiler doesn't go deep enough to comprehend this. Anyway, what you want is the accepted answer, which not only fixes the variable initialization, but changes also the logic in order to fix another problem that was not part of the initial question.